# Xcode: Copy files from one Project to another in same workspace

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xib, xcode-workspace

I am currently working on legacy code for an iPhone application. Someone has implemented a feature in the iPhone and now I am trying to implement it into iPad.

To start with I have decided to drag the files from the iPhone project into the iPad and get it working. Then I am going to find a solution where by both projects can share the same code.

However I have copied the files from the iPhone project into the ipad project and have a problem with the xib. The outlets are still referencing the iPhone version.

So when I remove the IBOutlets from the iPad version the connections still remain because the iPhone xib has not been touched. However when I remove the connections from the iphone project, it also removes the outlets from the ipad version.

These are both separate projects within the same workspace.

I am not sure why this is happening and also is there a way around copy the files without the file referencing the other project?

Comment: Just copy code from the old to new project and close old one. Then you can see real references and disconnected.