# 2 Projects in the same workspace xcode (code share)

Tags: ios, xcode, workspace, code-duplication

I am currently working on a workspace with 2 projects. One project does not depend on the other. They are separate entities.

However a previous developer has implemented new features on the one project and I now need to implement the same features on the other project.

However the classes that he has implemented in the one project import other classes. These classes are not currently in the project I am working on.

What is the best way to share these classes across the 2 projects. I don't really want to copy the files over because that would making supporting the 2 projects harder. I.e - We would have to update both projects at the same time and is much more prone to a mistake.

Also when you do copy files from one project to the other (clicking copy) I am having a lot of issues with my project conflicting with the other project. Here is a question I asked about this issue: [Xcode: Copy files from one Project to another in same workspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30125752/xcode-copy-files-from-one-project-to-another-in-same-workspace)

**Is there an elegant way to share these files across the two projects?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you work with Git, take a look on submodule